# How to add location class to android app?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that sends your location on `SMS` and I need to implement the location.

I tested some code on another project and the code worked well.

I got the code from the test project and made a new `class` and put the code there but something isn't working.

```
public class LocMng extends MainActivity {


private Button b;
private TextView t;
private TextView k;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;

final int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpol);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            t.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    configure_button();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            configure_button();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void configure_button(){
    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    ,10);
        }
        return;
    }
    // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 10000, 10, listener);
        }
    });
}

}
```

When I press the button nothing happens.

Here is the whole file if needed
https://github.com/Tony459/SO-ASt/tree/master/For%20SO
Somethings in the code are Turkish but they are not important

Answer (score 0):

you are not requesting the location correctly , try to get the location this way :

```
 private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }

    return bestLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checking code should probably look more like this:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
         ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
         ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return  ;
    }
```

If the 'If' statement is false, then it doesn't return and the b.setOnClickListener gets executed.